# How to activate my own Jakarta HttpAuthenticationMechanism implementation in Jakarta EE app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly-26, jakarta-ee-security-api, jakarta-ee-9

I am creating an simple **Jakarta EE 9** app. Because of my own reason, I have to implement my own HttpAuthenticationMechanism (I am not using built-in [HttpAuthenticationMechanism](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/security/enterprise/authentication/mechanism/http/httpauthenticationmechanism) CDI beans).

I am having an issue with activating my own HttpAuthenticationMechanism. In my login servlet, I try to call [SecurityContext.authenticate(request, response, AuthenticationParameters)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/security/enterprise/securitycontext#authenticate-jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-jakarta.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.AuthenticationParameters-) to process a login manually, **but my own HttpAuthenticationMechanism never get called. It was supposed to be called.**

**My own HttpAuthenticationMechanism & its annotations**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Alternative
@jakarta.annotation.Priority(jakarta.interceptor.Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
@AutoApplySession

public class MyOwnHttpAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

    @Override
    public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpMessageContext httpMessageContext)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        
        // Never called
    }
}
```

**As you see, I already added @Alternative and @Priority to activate the bean.**

**My environment:**

- Jakarta EE 9.1
- Wildfly 26 preview for Jakarta EE 9
- I also changed **Integrated JASPI** from ON to OFF on the Wildfly.
- my jboss-web.xml: < security-domain>**jaspitest**< /security-domain>
- Java 11

**Any helps? Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found out what was wrong. There was NO security domain 'jaspitest' in Wildfly 26. This security domain existed in Wildfly before by default, but no longer exists**. That was the reason why my own HttpAuthenticationMechanism did not get invoked.

**Solution**: Use Security Domain **'other'** instead, OR remove the security-domain tag from jboss-web.xml, OR your own security domain